# Log In with Openssh Private Key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I got a **.pk** file, which inside I have a key that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

CONTENT

-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

1. What is a **.pk** extension file? Perhaps short of **p**rivate **k**ey? Switching the extension to .pem for example, or to none, will make any difference?
2. How can I ssh with this key. Is it like the regular way?
   -> `ssh -i key.pk user@IP`
   I got the following error:
   -> `Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "Private Key" is what the abbreviation stands for.
You are also correct in thinking that the file types are arbitrary; some organizations use different naming standards.

Your **public** key needs to be added to your user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote server before the key pair can be used.  If you do not have the public key, the following command will retrieve a public key from a private key:

```sh
$ ssh-keygen -y -f private_key_file > public_key_file.pub
```